# How to populate a tableview from two mysql tables which are in same database in javaFx?

Tags: java, mysql, uitableview, javafx, fxml

I have a mySQL database which name is "Students". It have two tables. First one is "Student Details" table and another one is "Student Marks" table. So i have two model classes for each tables.

"Student Details" table Columns - stuId, name, address, contact

"Student Marks" table columns - markId, stuId, subId, marks

i already design tableview from scenebuilder and which have columns following

- stuId
- name
- totalMarks

So i want to populate above tableview like that. But student name and marks details are in different tables. 
please someone can give me a sample programme to do above activity? 
I use netBeans IDE....
Here is my DBConnection Class....

```
package dbConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {
    private static DBConnection dbConnection;
    private final Connection conn;

    private DBConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Students","root","xxxx");
    }

    public static DBConnection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        if(dbConnection == null){
            dbConnection = new DBConnection();
        }
        return dbConnection;
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please use http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? We can write you a query which will do that. You have to join to tables using foreign key.

Comment: after join two tables what do i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Join** in your SQL query.

```
SELECT StudentDetails.stuid,StudentDetails.name,StudentMarks.marks
FROM StudentDetails
INNER JOIN StudentMarks
ON StudentDetails.stuid = StudentMarks.stuid;
```

More about SQL Joins in [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)